# How to update a column value from another table

Tags: list-view

The title might be a litle confusing, but I dont know how to explain it better.
Here is my problem:
I have three lists - LIST1, LIST2, LIST3.

LIST1 and LIST2 are not interesting.
LSIT3 contains all the records from LIST1 and LIST2 and some other records.
LIST3 should show all the records that are not updated within the last 5 days.
LIST3 should also take in consideration, when some record is updated in LIST1 or LIST2 the last 5 days, it should not be displayed.

In other words LIST3 should show all records that:
- are not modified the last 5 days in LIST3
AND  are not modified the last 5 days in LIST2
AND  are not modified the last 5 days in LIST1

Comment: Sorry, i was so happy to finish this post, that i forgot that thank all those that will (hope so) try to help me:)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question - title asks something about updating column values yet the body of your question seems to be asking about how to structure a view?

Comment: Yes, because i was thinking how the update the MODIFIED column in LIST3 to be equal to the newest MODIFIED column in LIST1 or LIST2.

Comment: So what is your question? You already have all three lists? Are items tied together somehow across lists?

Comment: @Boris, When you say that the item in LIST3 is also in LIST1 or LIST2, do you mean the values of all the fields are the same? If an item gets updated in LIST1 that is also in LIST3 are they still equal? If not, should LIST3 be automatically updated?

Comment: Fix question so it is clearer what the problem is. Also I cant see why you would want tree lists; it looks like 3 views on one list would do the same

Comment: @Kit Menke - Yes, there a column username.

Comment: @Laurie - the only information that needs to be updated in the Modified Date. If some record in LIST1 or LIST2 is modified, the Modified Date should be updated also in LIST3.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague but there is a solution that I think might work for you.

Create an Event Receiver and attach it to List1 and List2 so that when they are updated they also update the appropriate item in List3.  With that in place, your views should work as expected in List3.

Comment: Event Receiver are created with Visual Studio right?

Comment: Yes creating an event receiver requires writing some code in Visual Studio and deploying it to the server.